# How to split this specific vbs script in 2 or 3 lines?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

This script is just perfect for me but please how to split the message in 2 or 3 lines to show in the popup?

```
@echo off

call :MsgBox "Would you like to go to URL?"  "VBYesNo+VBQuestion" "Click yes to go to URL"
if errorlevel 7 (
    echo NO - don't go to the url
) else if errorlevel 6 (
    echo YES - go to the url
    start "" "http://www.google.com"
)

exit /b

:MsgBox prompt type title
setlocal enableextensions
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
>"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit msgBox("%~1",%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Comment: This is batch file not VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an idea to test with :

```bat
@echo off
Set "URL=https://www.google.com"
Call :MsgBox "Would you like to go \n to URL : %URL% ? \n YES go to this URL \n or \n NO to quit this script" ^
"VBYesNo+VBQuestion" "Click yes to go to URL"
if errorlevel 7 (
    echo NO - don't go to the url
) else if errorlevel 6 (
    echo YES - go to the url
    start "" "%URL%"
)

exit /b

:MsgBox prompt type title
setlocal enableextensions
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
>"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit MsgBox(Replace("%~1","\n",vbcrlf),%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

Comment: @user854146 in this case you should  mark this answer as accepted.Just [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I wonder ,why people here downvote this answer ??? at least leave a comment to show us the reason if this deserve a downvote !

Answer (score 0):

If you code the text for your line like this:

```
"Line 1" & vbCrLf & "Line 2" & vbCrLf & "Line 3"
```

You'll get a result that looks like this:

```
Line 1  
Line 2  
Line 3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: call :MsgBox "Line 1" & vbCrLf & "Line 2" & vbCrLf & "Line 3"  "VBYesNo+VBQuestion" "Click yes to go to URL"